# If I don't have same numbers of line in text file it is not showing the button

Tags: c#

Hey Guys I have two buttons who are reading from two text files and when i click first button it is showing me that many buttons as I have lines in text file when i click on second button it is showing the same but when i click on the first again it is not showing that many buttons it is showing me how many lines i have in the second file

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button10.ResetText();
    button11.ResetText();
    button12.ResetText();

    string line1 = File.ReadLines(@"text1.txt").First();
    {
        button10.Text = line1;
    }
    string line2 = File.ReadLines(@"text1.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    {
        button11.Text = line2;
    }
    string line3 = File.ReadLines(@"text1.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(2);
    {
        button12.Text = line3;
    }
        
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(button10.Text))
    {
        button10.Visible = false;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(button11.Text))
    {
        button11.Visible = false;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(button12.Text))
    {
        button12.Visible = false;
    }
}          
                    
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button10.ResetText();
    button11.ResetText();
    button12.ResetText();
                        
    string line1 = File.ReadLines(@"text2.txt").First();
    {
        button10.Text = line1;
    }
    string line2 = File.ReadLines(@"text2.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    {
        button11.Text = line2;
    }
    string line3 = File.ReadLines(@"text2.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(2);
    {
        button12.Text = line3;
    }
       
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(button10.Text))
    {
        button10.Visible = false;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(button11.Text))
    {
        button11.Visible = false;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(button12.Text))
    {
        button12.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding the button if its related value is empty but you never show it again when it's not empty. The second time you click the first button it still remembers the visibly state from when you clicked button 2. You need to explicitly reset the visibility of the button to `true` when it has previously been set to `false`.

---

Basically you need to do the following with each of your checks to set the button's visibility; set the visibility to `true` to over ride any previous logic that set it to `false`.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(button10.Text))
{
    button10.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    button10.Visible = true; // make it visible again
}
```

That said you can simplify the above `if/else` visibility check into a single line, like so...

```
button10.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(button10.Text);
```

---

Below is your revised code with the single line visibility check and the unnecessary `{` `}` (brackets) removed around the lines that set the button text....

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button10.ResetText();
    button11.ResetText();
    button12.ResetText();

    string line1 = File.ReadLines(@"text1.txt").First();
    button10.Text = line1;            
    string line2 = File.ReadLines(@"text1.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    button11.Text = line2;
    string line3 = File.ReadLines(@"text1.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(2);
    button12.Text = line3;

    // set visibility based on button text
    button10.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(button10.Text);
    button11.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(button11.Text);
    button12.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(button12.Text);
}

private void button1a_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button10.ResetText();
    button11.ResetText();
    button12.ResetText();

    string line1 = File.ReadLines(@"text2.txt").First();
    button10.Text = line1;
    string line2 = File.ReadLines(@"text2.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    button11.Text = line2;
    string line3 = File.ReadLines(@"text2.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(2);
    button12.Text = line3;

    // set visibility based on button text
    button10.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(button10.Text);
    button11.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(button11.Text);
    button12.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(button12.Text);
}
```